# Personal tab teams add configuration/read configuration from bot

Tags: tabs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have an application in MS Teams. It is a message extension and a simple bot. This application needs a REST API set from the user to work properly. If this REST API is set and the user logs in, everything works ok. UserState with REST API url is stored in blobstorage.

I currently want to add a personal tab as well. The tab should retrieve data from the users REST API and display the grid. SSO works ok, but the problem occurs with loading the REST API. I don't know how to get the REST API value that the user entered in the messaging extension/bot settings.

I know the setting is possible for other types of tab (team and channel) but this doesn't work for personal tab.

Is there any way to read the data stored in the BOT (User state) within the tab/possibly modify it on the tab and save it back to Bot?  Or the only option is to do some user status management completely on our side?

Alternatively, is there any context that can be called within the tab to save the user state there similiar to Office.roamingSettings?

Comment: Please have look into this sample-https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management
Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have this up and running. But the question is how do I access the user settings in Blob Storage within the tab.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on User setting. which user setting you want to access?

Comment: Ones saved during "config" action in messaging extension. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet#respond-to-user-requests